# wrong date article in serp and changed to 1997 or 1998

Tags: search-results

i used last version yoast seo
me have 550 article in site.
all article 2 week ago are valid date puslished but now changed to 1997 or 1998

in head and the database date is valid but in google serp date is 1997 or 1998
my code in head webpage:

```
<meta property=”article:published_time” content=”2019-10-19T15:30:04+00:00″ />
```

that is valid

Comment: What is your site?  Do you have any other dates in your pages?  Google doesn't always rely on the meta information to determine dates.

Comment: my website is " academyzibaei.com "
in 63 serp is valid date but in all article invalid

Comment: If I search for `site:academyzibaei.com` I see some of those invalid dates on the second page of the Google results.   I can't tell where it is coming from.     If I look through the source code for possible dates, I don't see any:  `curl -s 'https://academyzibaei.com/%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86%DA%AF/' | grep -oE '.{1,30}\b(19|20)[0-9]{2}\b.{1,30}'`

Comment: how fix that?
me test all way and no fix that
please help me

Comment: i fixed that
thanks for asnwer brooooooooo :)